# Turn image from grayscale to coloured while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, grayscale

I am trying to make an animation where the image turns from grayscale to coloured as we scroll downwards,the image stays in its place until it fully turns coloured and where the height of coloured part is the amount scrolled and the leftover is gray. I have tried the following code but here, the image turns into coloured all at once .

One of the tricks that could be used were to have the grayscale image over a coloured one and change the height of grayscale image which I was unable to implement.

```js
const targets = document.querySelectorAll(".colored");
const isAnimated = "is-animated";
const threshold = 0.5;

function callback(entries, observer) {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    const elem = entry.target;
    if (entry.intersectionRatio >= threshold) {
      elem.classList.add(isAnimated);
      //observer.unobserve(elem);
    } else {
      elem.classList.remove(isAnimated);
    }
  });
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, { threshold });
for (const target of targets) {
  observer.observe(target);
}
```

```css
/* RESET RULES & HELPER CLASSES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
:root {
  --blue: #0a0c10;
  --gray: #ededed;
  --white: white;
  --red: red;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

body {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.cover {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.vh-100 {
  height: 100vh;
}

.hero-section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hero-section p {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.hero-section,
.page-footer {
  color: var(--white);
  background: var(--blue);
}

.section h2 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  padding: 10vh;
}

.section h2 a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 var(--blue);
  transition: all 0.15s;
}

.section h2 a:hover {
  color: var(--white);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -45px 0 var(--blue);
}

.img-wrapper {
  display: grid;
}

.img-wrapper div {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}


/* CLIP-PATH STYLES
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.grayscale {
  filter: grayscale(1);
  background-color: var(--gray);
}

.colored {
  clip-path: inset(0 100% 0 0);
  transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

.colored[data-animation="to-left"] {
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 100%);
}

.colored[data-animation="to-top"] {
  clip-path: inset(0 0 100% 0);
}

.colored[data-animation="to-bottom"] {
  clip-path: inset(100% 0 0 0);
}

.colored.is-animated {
  clip-path: inset(0);
}


/* FOOTER
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
.page-footer {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10vh;
}

.page-footer p + p {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.page-footer span {
  color: var(--red);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section class="hero-section vh-100">
  <div>
    <h1>Grayscale to Color Effect</h1>
    <p> Scroll down</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section">
  <h2>by <a href="https://pixabay.com/el/users/mark_mook_fotografie-3466195" target="_blank">Mark Mook</a></h2>
  <div class="vh-100 img-wrapper">
    <div class="grayscale cover" style="background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/portrait1.jpg); background-position: top;"></div>
    <div class="colored cover" style="background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/portrait1.jpg); background-position: top;"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section">
  <h2>by <a href="https://pixabay.com/el/users/bessi-909086" target="_blank">Besi</a></h2>
  <div class="vh-100 img-wrapper">
    <div class="grayscale cover" style="background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/portrait2.jpg); background-position: top;"></div>
    <div class="colored cover" data-animation="to-left" style="background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/portrait2.jpg); background-position: top;"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section">
  <h2>by <a href="https://pixabay.com/el/users/nastya_gepp-3773230" target="_blank">Anastasia Gepp</a></h2>
  <div class="vh-100 img-wrapper">
    <div class="grayscale cover" style="background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/portrait3.jpg); background-position: top;"></div>
    <div class="colored cover" data-animation="to-bottom" style="background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/portrait3.jpg); background-position: top;"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section">
  <h2>by <a href="https://pixabay.com/el/users/doanme-4958892" target="_blank">Doris Metternich</a></h2>
  <div class="vh-100 img-wrapper">
    <div class="grayscale cover" style="background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/portrait4.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="colored cover" data-animation="to-top" style="background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/portrait4.jpg);"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<footer class="page-footer">
  <p>
    <small>Images from <a href="http://pixabay.com/" target="_blank">Pixabay</a>
    </small>
  </p>
  <p>
    <small>Made with <span>❤</span> by <a href="https://georgemartsoukos.com/" target="_blank">George Martsoukos</a>
    </small>
  </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Does anyone have a helpful solution?

Comment: I'm working thru this same issue now and searching around seems most Q&A aren't quite the same as I'm looking for, only this one sounds the same and sadly no answer yet.